# Is there a need for so many regex tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

There's [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), [regex-negation](/questions/tagged/regex-negation), [regex-lookarounds](/questions/tagged/regex-lookarounds), [regex-greedy](/questions/tagged/regex-greedy), [regex-group](/questions/tagged/regex-group), etc.  I'm not saying that all tags associated with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) are superfluous, but these last four tags seem to be.

I don't believe that tag synonyms will solve this issue, so how does one go about completely getting a tag removed or remapped to a different tag?  This part of the question is somewhat general, but specifically, can we please remove the latter 4 tags (at least, I'm sure others are superfluous too)?

Comment: If you think that those 4 are superfluous but others are not, then which regex-related tags do you feel are okay? To me, those 4 seem to be specialised areas/topics. I'd keep them around.

Comment: given the regex tag as a whole is pretty much a code-for-me request log with pretty much zero use for anyone anywhen, I guess these subtags are actually one of the better places in this country. I say let them be.

Comment: We're a country now?

Comment: @Arjan I was just being conservative, but felt that those in particular were kinda worthless.  They add nothing to regex.  It's not like these are complicated sub-fields of a discipline; they're absurdly simple subsets of a relatively small area.  I see no reason why someone would ever feel the need to specify "group" or "greedy", etc. when all they really need is "regex."  They seem like they just take up room and potentially confuse new posters.  From what I can tell, almost every post is cross linked with regex, anyway.

Comment: I'm rather conflicted here - on the one hand, saying "this question is specifically about lookarounds" (for example) is useful. On the other hand, I don't think all that many questions actually are. I wonder how many of those 18 upvoters actually know enough about regex and regex questions on [so] to justify voting here.

Comment: @Dukeling While that may be true sometimes, if the OP only tags the the specific sub-tag, it's quite possible that OP's approach doesn't make sense and that the true problem should be handled by a different regex approach, in which case the sub-tag actually hurt.  There are a lot of things to consider, but I'm pretty sure that grouping all of these into one tag will help more than it will hurt.

Comment: @SteveP. I'm talking about questions specifically about how some regex construct works, not really about finding some regex for a pattern, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958747/how-does-mn-exactly-n-times-twice-work). It's useful to be able to distinguish these questions from the hordes of questions about writing a regex for a pattern. Chris' suggestion may have some merit (except that "regex.*" most probably isn't a valid tag, and it's far from descriptive), as long as it's very selectively applied.

Comment: @Dukeling I gotcha, but those questions are rather rare...

Answer (score 19):

Replace all regex-related tags with the `regex.*` tag

Comment: That's hilarious.

Comment: How make regex to use regex tag on SO? Help!